# Migrating a Django backend for a JS app to WordPress

Tags: php, django, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have a Django-based site with a JavaScript single page app which consumes a REST API built with the [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/). I need to migrate my site to WordPress, and from resources I have studied it seems that this should be fairly straightforward and painless, with the WordPress REST API assuming the role of my DRF API. I am new to WordPress development, however, and a number of aspects of any potential migration remain unclear to me. The main points are listed below:

- Should I simply convert my Django app to a WordPress plugin? This
  seems the simplest option, and I have already started doing this, but the app will only ever be available on my site, and all of the plugin tutorials I have found assume a
  public plugin, so I was wondering if there are other options. Also
  a plugin implies extending WordPress functionality, which I'm not doing
  (I guess?).
- Where do I store my data? It's read-only, and there's not much of it (only a couple of MB).
  In Django I have just used the admin interface to insert data, and
  run queries using the Django query API. What are the equivalent
  features in WordPress? Can I manually insert my data? And how would I
  then query it in my code?
- My records are not 'posts' in any meaningful sense. How do I define a
  database record that is not a post? I guess through defining a custom post type?

Many thanks for any advice/help.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to migrate from Django to WordPress? Might help understand what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @cabrerahector Thanks. Well it's an academic project, and we have a number of team members who are not developers, but still need to add content to the site. Also we get ready-to-go WordPress VM images from our institute's data centre. My role is purely to develop the JavaScript SPA, which will occupy one page on the site, and is backend-agnostic. The site itself is a non-blog, static site.

Comment: Why can't they use the Django admin to add content? Even if they can't it'd probably be less work to build a friendlier admin interface than to migrate to Wordpress.

Comment: @MatthewDaly The content they add is entirely different, nothing to do with the app. It's just standard text content, images, etc. The main site will be designed and maintained separately, even though the original intention was to have the entire thing based off Django.

Comment: @ChrisM You can easily find Django modules for stuff like that if you look, and you can pull that content in using DRF. Switching to Wordpress is likely to be far more work.